# Is it possible to attempt to summit Mont Blanc in at the end of April / start of May?

Tags: france, mountain-climbing, skiing

I'm currently planning to work a Ski season from December 2016 / April 2017 in France an hour away from Chamonix. At the end of the ski season I'd like to do something memorable to end my time working in France.

I was thinking about a possible summit to Mont Blanc, is this possible during the months of April / May or Is it better to do this in the Autumn months?

(I know fitness plays a huge part into the possible summit, but I am asking if it is possible to attempt a summit in late April / early May)

This would involve getting the Aiguille du Midi Cable Car to 3842m then attempt a 2 day summit trip with a guide.

Comment: http://www.highmountainguides.com/index.php/eng/What-we-do/Mountaineering-in-Chamonix/Climb-Mont-Blanc/Climb-Mont-Blanc-in-Autumn-Winter-Spring essentially seems to answer it. Most ascents in spring are made on skis and it is the second most popular season.

Comment: Contact a guide company like http://www.chamonix-guides.eu/ and ask. But note that the normal route is not from Aiguille du Midi, and guides may hesitate to take inexperience mountaineers.

Comment: I think you accepted a bit quickly, as I think my answer from the first Google hit is a bit weak -- if you're a ski teacher it makes a lot more sense to do it on skis, and maybe someone will show up who's actualy done it.

Comment: You may have luck finding asking on the Outdoors stack exchange site as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to the first Google hit http://www.chamonix.net/english/mountaineering/climb-mont-blanc , the route you describe is the "Cosmique Route", and it says ****The ideal period is from March to September (depending on conditions)**. So the answer to the question is yes.

However this route is also much more technical than the standard route (see the text), so besides endurance you also need good technique on steep glaciers and with ice axes, you need alpine experience.